# how to sum all numbers on the right side of a slash in one cell

Tags: excel-formula

i have some info like this in a excel sheet:

1a/1, 2a/1, 5c/6, 6d/1, 7q/5

all these are in one cell seperated by a comma,
i only want sum of the numbers on the right side of slash.
In the above example the answer should be 14.

Comment: are you allowed to use helper cells?  Can the cell be split into multiple cells?  There is a built in excel function called text to columns that will do this.  Also is it always the same number of number commas?  ie same number of number sets? Is the number to the right of the / always only 1 digit or could it be like 2b/42?

Answer (score 0):

```
=RIGHT(A1,1)+RIGHT(B1,1)+RIGHT(C1,1)+RIGHT(D1,1)+RIGHT(E1,1)
```

Assuming your original info is in A1, and you can perform a text to columns to split it into individual cells, and there are not more than 5 number sets to the string.

Alternatively you could put the following in F1 and copy it across to J1:

```
=--RIGHT(A1,1)
```

Then in K1 do a simple sum:

```
=SUM(F1:J1)
```